# How is it possible that lines in the end (which were not executed yet) affect the beginning of the code? And why does it throw an incorrect error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, syntax-error, identifier, referenceerror

So I had an `x is not defined` error in my code which confused me a little bit because `x` was already defined couple lines before. I had to spend some time tweaking my code, deleting and adding lines until I managed to understand why it was happening. After I removed every unnecessary information, now the code looks like this:

```
let foo = 2;
console.log(foo);

if (foo === 2){
    console.log(foo);
    let foo = 1;
}
```

It throws `foo is not defined` at line 5. An error pops out when I'm trying to `console.log(foo)` ! If I remove line 6 `let foo = 1;` the code works fine. I mean an error happens before I declare `foo` for a second time. So the first question is:

1. How is it possible that line 6 (which hasn't been executed yet) makes line 5 end up with an error?

The second thing I can't understand is why does it say `foo is not defined` instead of `foo has been already declared`. 
If I replace the second `let` with `var` an error will appear at line 6 and it will say `foo has been already declared` so it looks fine. But having `let` being set as the second identifier always throws an incorrect error.

2. Why does it throw an incorrect error?

After testing different scenarios I noticed that the outcome depends on which identifiers I use:

```
identifiers |            result
----------------------------------------------
  var var   |      the code works well
  var let   |       not defined error
  let var   | has been already declared error
  let let   |       not defined error
```

So the 3rd question is:

3. Why is everyone against of using `var` when in this scenario double using `var` is the only way the code works flawless? Is it an exception?

Comment: If you meant the code to work with the same variable (like it happens when you use `var var`), then you should just declare it only once (with `let`) and simply reassign it `foo = 1;` - without a second declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. How is it possible that line 6 (which hasn't been executed yet) makes line 5 end up with an error?

Because the scope of bindings (loosely, "variables") declared with `let`, `const`, and `class` is the entire block, not just from where they're declared to the end of the block. The time between code entering the block and the execution of the `let` statement is called the *Temporal Dead Zone* (TDZ), during which the binding exists but is uninitialized and cannot be used in any way. Just having `let foo` in the block shadows the outer `foo`, even before the `let foo` is encountered in the code flow.

Aside from scope, this TDZ is the big difference between `var` and `let` is that `var` creates a binding *and* initializes it to `undefined`, regardless of where the `var` statement is in the scope. In contrast, `let` (and `const` and `class`) create the binding, but *don't* initialize it until later, when the `let` (`const`, `class`) is encountered in the step-by-step execution of the code. You can't use an uninitialized binding.

> 2. Why does it throw an incorrect error?

It's not incorrect. You could argue it's poorly-worded. :-) Basically it's saying "you can't use `foo` here, it's not initialized." The current error message from V8 (the JavaScript engine in Chrome, Chromium, Brave, the new Chromium-based Edge, and Node.js) is, to my mind, clearer:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'foo' before initialization

Comment: FWIW, I go into some detail about how bindings work, the TDZ, etc. in Chapter 2 of my new book coming out in a couple of months. If you're interested, see my profile for details.

Comment: This makes it clear. Good explanation. But why using double var won't throw `has been already declared error`?

Comment: @narra_kk - Purely because `var` is defined that way in the spec, repeating `var` has no effect at all, but isn't defined as an error. The newer forms reflect a more modern approach. :-)

Answer (score 2):

When you declare a variable using `let` it is valid within the scope of the current code block.  Your second `let foo` declaration defines a separate `foo` than the first variable and it's only valid within the if-block. However you are using it before it is defined so you get the error correctly that it's not defined yet.

If you truly intend there to be two different `foo` variables, I'd recommend calling them something else (foo1 and foo2 for example) to avoid the conflict. Then it becomes clear that you are using the variable before it's defined.

```
let foo1 = 2;
console.log(foo1);

if (foo1 === 2){
    console.log(foo1);
    let foo2 = 1;
}
```

If you mean for line 5 to be using the first instance of `foo` set to 2, then you've hidden it by the new definition happening within the if-block of code.

If you mean for the `foo` that's set to 1 to be used on line 5 then you should move its definition to before its use.

Note that using `var` has a different result because the scope of `var` variables his broader than the scope of `let` variables. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) which has this definition:

> let allows you to declare variables that are limited to a scope of a
>   block statement, or expression on which it is used, unlike the var
>   keyword, which defines a variable globally, or locally to an entire
>   function regardless of block scope.

To try to make it more clear I've marked your code up with the state of the variables at each stage of the code:

```
let foo = 2;          // foo defined and set to 2
console.log(foo);     // foo defined and set to 2

if (foo === 2)        // foo defined and set to 2
{                     // <-- start of the if-block!
    console.log(foo); // foo not defined yet
    let foo = 1;      // foo defined and set to 1
}                     // <-- end of if-block!
console.log(foo);     // foo defined and set to 2
```

Comment: As far as I understand If I use `var` as the first identifier, the `foo` variable will be defined inside of the second block right? Then why does it throw `not defined error` if I have `let foo = 1;` as line 6?

Comment: Because by having the declaration anywhere in the if-block makes that the variable valid in that scope and hides the one declared by the `var` even. It doesn't make it valid for just half of the block.